# while it does work in the third line of the output it does not have a value

Tags: cmd

```
for /f "delims=.+-" %A in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do Set dt=%A
```

but the output is

```
 :\Users\diablo>Set dt=LoadPercentage
 :\Users\diablo>Set dt=1
 :\Users\diablo>Set dt=
```

while i want it only to keep the cpu loadpercentage(number)

Answer (score 0):

don't let it have more than one line...

```
for /f %a in ('wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /value^|find "="') do @set /a %a
echo %LoadPercentage%
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the header line and wrap around another `for /F` loop to avoid trailing lines that appear empty (actually they contain orphaned carriage-return characters caused by poor Unicode-to-ANSI conversion by `for /F`; a second `for /F` loop is the most reliable way of getting rid of them):

```cmd
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %A in ('wmic CPU get LoadPercentage') do @for /F "delims=" %B in ("%A") do set "dt=%B"
```

Alternatively, use another output format of `wmic` to not have to skip anything (still twice `for /F`):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %A in ('wmic CPU get LoadPercentage /VALUE') do @for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %B in ("%A") do set "dt=%B"
```

Since `LoadPercentage` holds a purely numeric value only, I removed the delimiters `.+-`.